# css transform scale issue in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transform

I am trying to make a website scale based on the document size.

So when the document is 0px<1024px there should be a responsive design. This is strait forward with css media query. On the scale 1024px<1950px the "normal" design should be shown. Also this is pretty easy and this two dimentions working very fine.

Now I want that, when the document is >1950px, the scale is going up. So that when for example the screen is 2000px the website has a transform scale(2).

For this I came up with this little solution:

```
$(document).ready(larg);
$(window).resize(larg);
function larg(){
    var startResizing = 1950;
    var documentWidth = $(window).width();
    console.log("documentWidth: "+documentWidth);
    if(documentWidth > startResizing){
        var scale = (documentWidth - startResizing) / 2000;
        var roundTwoDecimals = Math.round(scale * 100) / 100;
        scale = 1 + roundTwoDecimals;
        console.log(documentWidth +"-"+ startResizing+"="+(documentWidth - startResizing));
        console.log(scale);

        $("html").css("zoom", scale); // IE
        $("html").css("-moz-transform", "scale("+scale+")"); // Firefox
        $("html").css("-moz-transform-origin", "0 0");
        $("html").css("-o-transform", "scale("+scale+")"); // Opera
        $("html").css("-o-transform-origin", "0 0");
        $("html").css("-webkit-transform", "scale("+scale+")"); // Safari and Chrome
        $("html").css("-webkit-transform-origin", "0 0");
        $("html").css("transform", "scale("+scale+")"); // Standard Property
        $("html").css("transform-origin", "0 0");
    }else{ // Reset
        $("html").css("zoom", ""); // IE
        $("html").css("-moz-transform", ""); // Firefox
        $("html").css("-moz-transform-origin", "");
        $("html").css("-o-transform", ""); // Opera
        $("html").css("-o-transform-origin", "");
        $("html").css("-webkit-transform", ""); // Safari and Chrome
        $("html").css("-webkit-transform-origin", "");
        $("html").css("transform", ""); // Standard Property
        $("html").css("transform-origin", "");
    }
}
```

In Chrome this is working fine. But in Firefox there is one big problem:
The scaling is done also on the X axis and a horizontal scroll is generated. And my html/body tag that normally has 100% width does not fit in the window anymore. So the user has to scroll horizontal and that should be **not** the case (in chrome everything is fine).
What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
I now found out, that the complete point of view is scaled and that I have to set the width of the html tag down. So instead of usind 100% I not calculate the width with `100 / newScale` and this is working fine now :)

Comment: I would like to help you, but can you provide example in jsFiddle or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

To change your CSS this way is really bad practice. You might want to take a look at [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), where you can do this in a better practice and easier. This way of doing responsive scaling is supported in all modern browsers.

Comment: With media queries I can not do the same calculation. and the result still would be the same: after transform:scale() I get a horizontal scroll in firefox but not in chrome. So my real question that you overread is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Js (jQuery) is a bad practice for scaling website (wait for the website to be fully loaded, then change its size?)

Use `@media` insead:

```
@media (max-width:1023px) {
   /* scaled down */
   .body {transform: scale (50%); }
}

@media (min-width:1024px) and (max-width:1950px) {

}
@media (min-width:1951px) {
    /* scaled up */
    .body {transform: scale (200%); }
}
```

Comment: With media queries I can not do the same calculation. and the result still would be the same: after transform:scale() I get a horizontal scroll in firefox but not in chrome. So my real question that you overread is still there.